# GRMustache how to render a parent variable inside a loop?

Tags: mustache

This question is for using GRMustache in an iOS application. Although the documentation links to standard mustache docs.

I am looping through mustache data and in the root of the page there is a variable called #noAnimation. The variable works outside of the loop however it does not work inside my loop. How can I get a parent variable inside a loop.

I have tried {{../noAnimation}} and the rendering engine breaks.

```
{{#noAnimation}}Will Work{{/}}

{{# withPosition(data) }}
   <div class="title">{{ title }}</div>
   {{#noAnimation}}Will not work{{/}}
{{/ withPosition(data) }}
```

GRMustache Version

```
/**
 * The major component of GRMustache version
 * 
* @since v1.0
*/
#define GRMUSTACHE_MAJOR_VERSION 6

/**
 * The minor component of GRMustache version
 * 
 * @since v1.0
 */
#define GRMUSTACHE_MINOR_VERSION 7

/**
 * The patch-level component of GRMustache version
 * 
 * @since v1.0
 */
#define GRMUSTACHE_PATCH_VERSION 4
```

Comment: Which GRMustache version are you using (check GRMustacheVersion.h)?

Comment: I can't reproduce your bug. You may give more information.

Comment: Hi Gwendal, thank you for looking into the issue. I added the version file data to the original post. It could be related to our architecture. I'm not sure if a global variable should be available within a loop. There is nothing anywhere in the documentation that supports this because it's supposed to be logicless. Which this implementation may go against that. It's hard to test without a console log.

Comment: GRMustache is a Mustache engine, and as such is able to access a key in the parent context - unless it has been shadowed by the current context. And version 6.7.4 already had no know bug about it. Your issue is still quite unclear. What about providing here some minimal code that reveals your issue?